# gnuplot projecting contuer to the XZ and YZ plane

Tags: gnuplot, contour

I have a dataset that has x,y,z columns. I have created surface plot using gnuplot and contour on top and bottom as see below. Here is the dataset: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8evj5da7yco1xmo/datx.dat?dl=0

Below is the plot from the data in the link.

[image]

I'm trying to create a contour plot like the one below with contours on the side, how do I accomplish this in `gnuplot`?

[image]

Here is the solution http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.com/2010/ but I'm unable to replicate it for my dataset.

Comment: The lines on the xz and yz planes in your sample figure are clearly not contours in the normal sense;  in projection the "surface" is a self-overlapping multivalued function.  What are these lines exactly?  Are they just selected lines from the surface itself (e.g. f(x) at x = -2, -1, 0, 1, 2)  projected back onto the bounding plane?

Comment: Please provide a MWE of the initial plot. You are missing blank lines to mark the change of $y$ coordinate, which is useful for most gnuplot ways of plotting. Your plot would be easy to do with them, and could be done without too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linked solution uses a matrix as input data with row- and column-index as x,y coordinates and you have `x,y,z` data columns. You could write your z-values into a matrix, but then you will lose your x- and y-coordinates. You could also possibly add them as the first row and first column "headers", respectively (gnuplot calls this a non-uniform matrix, check `help matrix nonuniform`).

However, gnuplot can also plot `x,y,z` data as surface plot easily, especially if it is a regular grid (which seems to be the case with your data). However, this data has to be separated by empty lines into iso-curves (as @Joce mentioned in the comments).

The script below

- inserts empty lines into your data (gnuplot-only workaround without external tools)
- plots projection lines (what @Ethan already assumed) to the xz- and yz-plane
- plots contour lines on the surface and on the base

This was a bit of a struggle (with `set pm3d`, `set contour`, etc.) to get it work, but I think the result is what you were asking for. There is room for fine-tuning.
If there are simpler ways to do it, please let me know.

**Script:**

```
### plot surface with contours and projections
reset session

FILE = "SO70490999.dat"
colX = 1
colY = 2
colZ = 3

# 1. read file into datablock, 2. insert marker when both x- and y-values change, 3. get xmax and ymax
set table $Temp
    x1 = y1 = xmax = ymax = NaN
    plot FILE u (x0=x1,x1=column(colX),y0=y1,y1=column(colY), \
         xmax!=xmax || x1>xmax ? xmax=x1:0, ymax!=ymax || y1>ymax ? ymax=y1:0, \
         sprintf("%g %g %g",x1,y1, column(colZ)).(x0!=x1 && y0!=y1 && x0==x0 ? " #" : '')) w table
unset table
# insert empty line before lines with marker
set print $Data
    do for [i=1:|$Temp|] {
        if (strstrt($Temp[i],"#")>0) { print ""}
        print $Temp[i]
    }
set print

# plot contour lines into a datablock
myContours = "-242.2, -242.5, -243, -244, -245, -246, -247"
set cntrparam level discrete @myContours
set contour both
set table $Contours
    splot $Data u 1:2:3 w l
unset table
unset contour

set view 55, 300
set key noautotitle
set xyplane relative 0

splot for [i=0:99:5] $Data every  ::i::i u (xmax):2:3 w l, \
      for [i=0:99:5] ''    every :::i::i u 1:(ymax):3 w l, \
                     '' u 1:2:3 w pm3d, \
      for [i=1:words(myContours)] $Contours index i u 1:2:3 w l lc i, \
      for [i=1:words(myContours)] $Contours index i u 1:2:(-400) w l lc i, \
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]